# Symfony filters out my script from loading

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, symfony-1.4

I write a symfony-based website. There are some popup windows (to register, to login, to change password). I load them with a jQuery AJAX request ($.get) simply by requesting http://example.com/module/action. Although popup loads html properly there are no scripts that are present at http://example.com/module/action requested normally.

Does anybody know how to disable this symfony feature? Or know  elegant workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Add restriction to your route:

```
route_name:
  url: route_path.:sf_format
  # sf_format: json sets default format to json
  param: { module: module_name, action: action_name, sf_format: json }
  # add restrictions
  requirements:
    sf_format: json
```

Solution, provided by Pedro @pedro-casado, is quite good (I used it in some of my previous projects), but after some time, I realised, that the **right way** is to add restrictions to the route. That way Symfony simply rejects all requests, except XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want that the page loads only when is calling by ajax?

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer